# how to import 'tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decoder' in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, seq2seq

I used 'tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decoder' in tensorflow1.0 and now I want to use it in tensorflow2.0; 
but I don't know how to import it in tensorflow2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0, [`seq2seq`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/README.md) module has been moved to `TensorFlow addons`

To install it run:

```
pip install tensorflow_addons
```

Here is the [migration guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/README.md#sample-code-and-migration-guide-from-tf-1x) for you to upgrade your code.

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: I am sorry for miss typed before and you have explained this matter so clear that I have got it; so thank you very much; Now I have some confused about detail of this function as which I have updated the question.